# Connect to a Django postgres database remotely

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Postgres for a production system, and I would like to be able to connect to this database remotely to integrate the information with other systems.

My configuration looks classic like follows :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myipgoeshere', 'mydomainnamegoeshere']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to connect to this database from another machine what should I use as hostname on that machine ?

I need to provide information about

```
Host
Database
Port
User
Password
```

In my config, host is localhost, but I cannot use this as remote hostname, should we use the IP address instead ? Also will the port be the default postgres one?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `"HOST"` like the usual host in a URL, for example a domain name or IP address.

To specify the port, you can add a field called `"PORT"` to your database config. The default port for Postgres is `5432`, but can be any valid port.

For example:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # ...
        'HOST': 'mydatabasehost.com', # e.g. or 192.168.0.10
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, changing 'localhost' in the settings with IP address is breaking the system (Internal Server Error 500)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issues by adding the IP in the postgress config file which has localhost by default, and after I started using IP in the django config